# STM32 IAP Application Jump Condition Not Satisfied

Tags: memory, stm32, bootloader, remap

I have a boot code at 0x08000000 and an application code at 0x08060000. I can jump to application from boot code if I comment out the condition check shown below:

```
//if (( (*(__IO uint32_t*)0x08060000) & 0x2FFE0000 ) == 0x20000000)
{
    JumpAddress = *(__IO uint32_t*)( 0x08060000 + 4 );
    Jump_To_Application = (pFunction)JumpAddress;
    __set_MSP( *(__IO uint32_t*)0x08060000 );
    Jump_To_Application();
}
```

The condition is not satisfied as the left side is equal to 0x20020000. I don't understand why it is 0x20020000 instead of being 0x20000000.

Why do we check the content of the start address with 0x20000000. What is stored in this memory address and what should it be normally?

Comment: Where did this code come from?  I suspect it's for a different version of the processor, with a slightly different memory layout and therefore a different valid range for this value (apparently the initial stack pointer for the application).

Comment: If you search on Google for STM32 IAP, you would see this condition. My processor is STM32F417.

Comment: i.e: http://www.onarm.com/forum/21181/

Comment: That link is to code for a low-end STM32F100 part with only 8K RAM.  The valid range for the stack pointer is therefore rather small compared to the part you're using, which apparently has 192K RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a vector table that's located at these addresses (at `0x08000000` for bootloader and at `0x08060000` for application respectively). The first value stored in the vector table is the reset value of the stack pointer.

You can check this link for more information: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABIFJFG.html

Why you'd want to check this value this way, one may only guess. It is likely there to act as a kind of safety check to see whether there *may* be a valid application loaded. It's definitely not sufficient and doesn't guarantee much (e.g. half of the application may be loaded). It also depends entirely on your memory layout and where in RAM you decide to place your stack. I assume you copy-pasted (or generated) some portion of the code responsible for memory layout in your application, then copy-pasted - from another source - this portion of the code that has the check in question. Those two will likely not work together very well.

Comment: I check like this because I saw many sample codes on internet checking this condition. Here is an example: http://www.onarm.com/forum/21181/

Comment: @sanchop22 As I've said, you found it under this link, which is separate from how memory is laid out in your application. In other words - it's likely not going to work. You may safely adjust this check to fit your application. Again, it's not a perfect check: checksum over entire application is much better in this case, it also makes it impossible for you to change application RAM layout (stack location at least) in the future as it's hardcoded into your bootloader code.

Comment: Ok, I understand very well. I've also found where this 0x20000 coming from. Thanks a million.